# Can I catch Groudon after defeating him?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I have only been a pokemon trainer for about two weeks, so I admit that I lack the experience of a veteran trainer. However, I have already defeated the eight gym leaders in my region (including my father!) and disrupted the criminal actions of a group of scientific thug fanatics.

Despite my obvious natural talent, I feel like I have made a blundering mistake. In my eagerness to save the world from the aforementioned apocalyptic extremist group, I defeated their cataclysmic Primal Groudon without a moments hesitation. It was then I realized the unfortunate selflessness of my actions--I should have captured the beast for my own use!

I returned to the Cave of Origins, but I can't find him in either of the two placed I confronted him earlier. Is there any way to re-encounter this leviathan, or have I entirely wiped the legend from the face of the earth?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Ah, I have heard mention of "The Elite Four" but have not yet encountered them. This could be what I'm looking for!

Comment: Thanks, for the help. I felt pretty silly when I realized that the Groudon had been asleep, and wounded, and I didn't catch him when I had the chance... Now I just have to one-shot the Elite Four with my Latios and head back to the Cave of Origins!